# Ajax success does not work without alert message

Tags: php, json, ajax

Ajax success does not work without alert message.
there is no error in the console.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Sensor/ConnectionTypeList",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'model_id': model_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data); //not runnig
                //alert(''running);

                if (document.getElementById("offset")) {
                    document.getElementById("offset").value = data[0].offset;
                }

                if (document.getElementById("multiplier")) {
                    document.getElementById("multiplier").value = data[0].multiplier;
                }

                if (document.getElementById("func")) {
                    document.getElementById("func").value = data[0].func;
                }

                if (document.getElementById("meas_command")) {
                    document.getElementById("meas_command").value = data[0].meas_command;
                }

                if (document.getElementById("read_command")) {
                    document.getElementById("read_command").value = data[0].read_command;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error.');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ajax success blog does not work without "alert('running')" message ;

Comment: json data is coming in and looks good.

Comment: do you see data with `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Yes,   Cosole output:   address: "9"
func: "fonksiyon"
ConType: "Analog"
chanel: "1"
marka_id: "10"
model_adi: "CS4.006WR/WRH"
model_id: "17"
multiplier: "multiplier"
offset: "offset"
meas_command: "okuma"
read_command: "zaman"

Comment: so - the ajax function works but you cannot interpret and use the returned data. We do not know which of the HTML elements your callback refers to actually exist so we do not know which of the logic tests fails. Your callback uses array notation `data[0]` - but the data you posted looks a little like it could be JSON so I'd guess it ought to be just `data.offset` ?

Comment: Does sound like you’re receiving an array of objects from your endpoint, but an object. Console log  `JSON.stringify(data)` and update your question with that output.

Comment: i think data is returning single object.

Answer (score 0):

Is the result type JSON? In that case you need to parse the returned result in order to use it, like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Sensor/ConnectionTypeList",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'model_id': model_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('>>', data);
            ...
```

I always use '>>' (or something like that) inside a `console.log` to make sure you always see a console message, even if the result is empty. Check the console log to see if the result and its type.